# Creating a stored Proc that creates new user and password

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to MySQL. I was trying to create a procedure with two parameters:

1. user_name
2. password

...that will be generated and granted full rights:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `gen_user`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `gen_user`(`user_name` VARCHAR(10), `keyword` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
   CREATE USER `user_name`@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY `keyword`
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO `user_name`@'localhost'
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The error I get is:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`keyword`    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO `user_name`@'localhost'    FLUSH P' at line 3

Answer (score 1):

One mistake for sure:  Each of the 3 statements needs a `;` at the end.

Possibly the syntax calls for literals, not variables for `user_name` and `password`.  So use `CONCAT()`, `prepare`, `execute`, and `deallocate prepare` to build and execute the `CREATE` and `GRANT` statements.